# How to run jsx component with webpack/reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am getting my head around reactjs/webpack and I have built a simple reactjs app. In the app.js I got:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
            render() {
                console.log('testing ')
                return <div>
                    <h1>Hello, ES6 w React 0.13!</h1>
                </div>;
            }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

For some reason when I run the webpackserver there is no display of this component happening. This is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/',
        publicPath: './dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am also using gulp to start the server:

```
gulp.task('webpack-dev-server', function (c) {
    var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);

    myConfig.devtool = 'eval';
    myConfig.debug = true;

    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    }).listen(myConfig.devServer.port, 'localhost', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw new gutil.PluginError('webpack-dev-server', err);
        }
        gutil.log('[webpack-dev-server]', 'http://localhost:8080/index.html');
    });
});
```

How can I display the jsxcomponent?

Comment: Any errors in console? You must render your top level element in the DOM with `ReactDOM.render`, are you doing this somewhere?

Comment: hi, just added some more code and ref to repo

Comment: You're rendering `<Application />`, but your class is `Applications`. And you should call `ReactDOM.render`, not `React.render`.

Comment: Just tried this, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned your repo and found what was wrong:

1. First of all, as mentioned, your class is named `Applications` and you're rendering `<Application />`. So, rename your class to `Application`.
2. Instead of using `React.render`, you should call `ReactDOM.render`
3. Render to the `<body>` tag. As the HTML is auto generated by the `webpack-dev-server` (by default), there is no `root` or `app` element. Like this:

   ```
   ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
   ```
4. You can remove `publicPath: './dist/'` from your configuration file. It's affecting the `webpack-dev-server` root folder. Just let `path: __dirname + '/',`, for testing.

   But, after you can change it to `path: __dirname + '/dist'`. This way, when running `webpack` command, it will generate the bundled file at this location: `dist/bundle.js`.

   Note that `webpack-dev-server` does not generate the output file. It builds it **in memory**.
5. And, at the end, you can run `webpack-dev-server` calling from your app root folder `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`. Don't need grunt here, as we're just testing.

Go to your browser and point to: **http://localhost:8080/bundle** (note the url: path matches the output filename). You can change this later and serve your custom folder (create your own index html file) with options like `--content-base`.

The component now should be rendered.

Comment: Many thanks for the elaborate answer, just one question. Where do I need the bundle.js file for if it is running in memory?

Comment: @bierhier you're welcome. The server builds the file in memory if the build is not there. Try modifying your config key `output.path` to `__dirname + '/dist'` and run `node_modules/.bin/webpack` command. It will generate your bundle into the `dist` folder. Then run `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` and try to modify your component (text inside your <h1> tag). It will update in the browser.

Comment: you from Brazil? brazilian bbq is my favourite food:)

Comment: @bierhier yes! here in south brazil we make a great bbq btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually render the component somewhere. For example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Applications />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

*EDIT:*

You edited your question and added to your code `React.render()`... but it should be `ReactDOM.render()` unless you are using a rather old version of React and as pointed out the component name does not match... you should be seeing various console errors if this is your actual code.

Comment: Just tried your suggestions without luck. There are no errors.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used gulp (I would try `webpack-dev-server` by itself) but I doubt that your code is executing at all. Shouldn't you be copying your HTML template into `dist`?